# passing a variable and a function using props in react native

Tags: react-native

I am passing a variable and a function using props in react native.

```
<ModalHeader message={'Мои заказы'}
     onPress={() => {
      goBack();
    }} />
```

In HeaderModel.js

```
static propTypes = {
    onPress: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    message: PropTypes.string
};



render() {
    return (     
     <Header style={styles.header}>
        <Left>
        <Button rounded transparent onPress={ this.props.onPress }>
        <Icon name='arrow-back'/>
        </Button>
        </Left>
        <Body>
            { this.props.message }                  
        </Body>
      </Header>
    );
}
```

When I run app, "app is not responding" error appears. What is wrong with my code? Any solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

Just change your ModalHeader to this:

```
<ModalHeader message={'Мои заказы'} onPress={this.goBack} />
```

This will pass the `goBack` function to `ModalHeader` Class